# Is "For most people, they..." redundant?

Tags: sentence-construction

For example,

> **For most people, they** would benefit from more exercise.

Is this construction more acceptable in spoken English, but considered poor writing? It's better to write:  **Most people** would benefit from more exercise.

Or this construction is perfectly fine and serves a purpose (which I can't grasp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is poor style. It does indeed suggest someone speaking and changing their intended sentence structure partway through.

The subject is expected to change after this scope qualifier:

> For most people, owning a dog is a manageable responsibility.

So when "they" appears, it sparks confusion as we look for a subject other than "most people" before realizing that's what it must refer to.

Comment: _For most people, more exercise would be beneficial._

Comment: How about the construction "As for me, I would like to buy a dress." I just heard it.